# Proof by structural induction that the reversal of w1w2 is the reversal of w2 + reversal of w1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I wanted to ask if the structural induction proof for this exercise can be considered correct in this way:

Use structural induction to prove that $(w1w2)^{R}=(w2)^{R}(w1)^{R}$

Attempted proof:
We will denote the empty string with $\lambda$

We know that $ \lambda^{R}$ is $ \lambda$

We know that (where $ \alpha$ is an alphabet letter) that $(w\alpha)^{R}$ is $ \alpha (w)^{R}$

$   (w1\lambda)^{R}=(w1)^{R}=(\lambda)^{R}(w1)^{R}$

So the property holds for the empty string

We want to prove then that, being $\alpha$ a generic letter of the alphabet that comprise the strings,

if  $(w1w2)^{R}=(w2)^{R}(w1)^{R}$, then $(w1w2\alpha)^{R}=(w2\alpha)^{R}(w1)^{R}$

We know that $(w1w2\alpha)^{R}$ is equal to $\alpha (w1w2)^{R}$.
By inductive hypothesis, $(w1w2)^{R}$ is equal to  $ (w2)^{R}(w1)^{R}$ so that we have

$ \alpha (w2)^{R}(w1)^{R}$

But by definition, $ \alpha (w2)^{R}$ is equal to  $ (w2\alpha)^{R}$. Hence $(w1w2\alpha)^{R}$ = $ (w2\alpha)^{R}$ $(w1)^{R}$

This completes the inductive step.

Is this the correct way to solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance